# UITableViewController showing white blank screen in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to make a very simple iOS app that has begins at one `UITableViewController` and when you click on each cell (a different manner kids should learn) it pushes that specific data to a `UIViewController`. I have added placeholder information in the cells, but when I run the simulator only a blank screen shows up. I  attach pictures and code below.

[image: Main Storyboard]

[image: Simulator]

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func backBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var names = ["Manner 1", "Manner 2", "Manner 3", "Manner 4", "Manner 6", "Manner 7", "Manner 8"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! Manner2Cell

        cell.name.text = names[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}

//Manner2Cell actually refers to the first cell. I know I know bad naming convention.

class Manner2Cell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Looking at all of this it looks like I have some repeated code. I feel like this is an easy fix but I just can't figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your `ViewController` as a `dataSource` for your `tableView` and adopt the protocol `UITableViewDataSource`.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ... {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self // Assigns ViewController as delegate for tableView 
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
```

Comment: A few things you should also check: y1) numberOfSections should NOT be returning zero. If you omit this it will return 1 by default which is probably what you need. 2) Make sure you properly set up the UITableView data source and delegate in your storyboard. Search for “storyboard set tableview delegate and data source” if you need help. 3) NumberOfRowsInSection should be returning names.count and not be hard coded to 8.

Answer (score 1):

The scene in the upper left of your Interface Builder screen snapshot looks like a `UITableViewController` (which is presumably the class you call `TableViewController`).

But your `numberOfSections` and `numberOfRowsInSection` both return zero. So you'll have a blank white screen. Frankly, it looks like the code intended for the first scene's `UITableViewController` subclass has been put in the second scene's view controller.

---

Your second scene (upper right of your snapshot) is a little confusing, because it looks like that's a `UITableViewController`, too, but it doesn't look like it should be a table at all. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there. Is it really a table with repeated occurrences or is it just supposed to be the details of the cell you selected in the first scene? If it's just supposed to be a "details" screen, then that should be a simple `UIViewController`, not a `UITableViewController`.